# Getting "permissionPreset" and "emailPermission" using google admin-sdk api

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api

How do I get "permissionPreset" and "emailPermission" using google admin-sdk api? Here also I didn't get. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list Can anyone please shed some light on this?

TIA
Riyaz.A

Answer (score 0):

There are no such values returned by the Directory API. You can get and update group settings using the [Group Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/). This offers much more fine grained options than the old Provisioning API settings did.